# How can I integrate spell-checking to redactor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, spell-checking, redactor

How can I add spell checking to the jQuery [Redactor](http://redactorjs.com/docs/examples/click-to-edit/) editor?  I have found a few spell checking JavaScript plugins, but none are easily integrated into Redactor.  Has anyone managed to do this successfully?  Using .NET, and need our own custom dictionary.

None of these spell checkers I've found can be easily integrated:

1. [JavaScript SpellCheck](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JQuery_SpellCheck_Plugin)
2. [WebSpellChecker](http://www.webspellchecker.net/v3/index.html) (expensive)
3. [JQuery Spell Checker](http://spellchecker.jquery.badsyntax.co.uk/) (uses Google spell check, no custom dictionary with .NET)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm the author of the jQuery SpellChecker you linked to. I have [re-written the plugin](https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker) and created [a demo page](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/redactor.html) showing how you can integrate it into the Redactor editor.