# Spell Checking With Redactor On Heroku

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, heroku, spell-checking, redactor

I am trying to implement spell check in [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) in a RoR application running on Heroku (Cedar stack).

The answer outlined in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357475/how-can-i-integrate-spell-checking-to-redactor) doesn't work for me because it requires being able to run PHP on my local server, which does not seem possible with Heroku. Even if I defeated the cross-origin protections, running PHP on a server external to my Rails app doesn't seem like a good idea.

[After the Deadline](https://github.com/search?q=%40Automattic+atd) seems like a possible solution, but the [After The Deadline gem](https://github.com/msepcot/after_the_deadline) returns the raw spell checker data without integration into Redactor.

Has anyone been able to successfully either:

- Implement [After The Deadline](http://blog.afterthedeadline.com/2010/01/05/add-grammar-and-spell-check-to-any-wysiwyg-editor/) with Redactor in a RoR environment?
- Gotten [jQuery Spellchecker](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/redactor.html) working in RoR and Heroku?

If not, are there any other solutions for spell check for Redactor in RoR on Heroku?

Comment: @derp, jquery-spellchecker not only need php, but also aspell library installed.

Answer (score 2):

*"are there any other solutions for spell check for Redactor in RoR on Heroku?"*

• Yes, there is a [**gem**](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) built by SammyLin which integrates Redactor to a rails app.

And please note heroku has a [PHP support and documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/php).

Comment: Did heroku also support aspell library that needed by jquery-spellchecker?

Answer (score 2):

What problems are you facing when you tried  [jQuery Spellchecker](https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker).
Cuz it seems like they have given the documentation plus i have found a demo of redactor with jquery spellchecker.

**[DEMO](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/redactor.html)**

i think jQuery Spellcheker documentation is pretty clear. Try it and if you find any problems then please update the question regarding the problem.

```
https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker/wiki/Documentation
```

Comment: jquery-spellcheck only have php webservice. It also require aspell library installed. My client only host rails app in heroku. I need a way to make it work with rails app in heroku, make the jquery-spellchecker request go to rails app instead of separated php script.